# Is there a program or tool like Spy ++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I remember long ago there was an app that went along with Microsoft's development kit that could be use to look at the actual message traffic of a program as it was running.  I think it was called spy++.  What is the equilivant today?

Comment: It is still included in Microsofts's Visual Studio package, not sure though if it must be downloaded separately. Also called SpyXX. Maybe check the installation folders, eg C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools. I had to copy-and-paste a shortcut on my desktop.

Comment: There is an equivalent nowadays. It is called Spy++. May be you are in a 64 bit environment, so you will need to use Spy++64, which comes together with Spy++ on your Visual C++ setup. I used to use also a non MS freeware thing called WinSpy, which I like very much, allowing one to change controls flags dynamically.